# Multiple variables significant

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients

I'm working on a regression of the price of the car compared to other factors. I can upload the data here but unsure it's necessary. The `summary` gives me:

```
Call:
lm(formula = cars$Price ~ cars$Mileage + cars$Cylinder + cars$Doors + 
    cars$Cruise + cars$Sound + cars$Leather + cars$Liter)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-13278  -5615  -1556   3996  32819 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    6.759e+03  1.877e+03   3.601 0.000337 ***
cars$Mileage  -1.698e-01  3.187e-02  -5.326 1.31e-07 ***
cars$Cylinder  3.792e+03  6.832e+02   5.551 3.87e-08 ***
cars$Doors    -1.543e+03  3.205e+02  -4.814 1.77e-06 ***
cars$Cruise    6.289e+03  6.580e+02   9.558  < 2e-16 ***
cars$Sound    -1.994e+03  5.718e+02  -3.487 0.000515 ***
cars$Leather   3.349e+03  5.977e+02   5.604 2.89e-08 ***
cars$Liter    -7.872e+02  8.671e+02  -0.908 0.364196    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7388 on 796 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4463,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4414 
F-statistic: 91.64 on 7 and 796 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

What bothers me is that almost all the variables are significant. I don't have that much data looking at the f-statistic, so I'm wondering if perhaps this is an overfit or is it okay? How do I fix it if not, and what may cause the problem?
Thanks

Comment: If you really meant to check for overfitting, then looking at p-values is completely unnecessary. If you want is out of sample performance, not inference, ditch the p-values and do proper cross-validation instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you’ve got hundreds of observations and only eight parameters, so with the close values of $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$, overfitting doesn’t seem to be a major issue for you. If you remain concerned about this, train on 80% of your observations and then test on the remaining 20% of the observations. Seeing similar MSEs should give you some peace of mind.

Why do you find the many significant parameters so surprising, though? To me, they all look like factors than would increase a car price. Further, I would kind of hope to have my parameters be significant. Excluding a variable because it’s parameter is insignificant is fraught with problems, but if I think it’s important enough to include in the model, I would hope for the math to reflect that! (It might not, either because I made a poor assumption about how the variable impacts the response or because I just don’t have the sample size to get significance, but significant parameters on important variables is logically consistent in my head.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was unsure if the amount of observations was big enough compared to the parameters. It does make sense, but I have learnt to never trust my instincts when doing stats ;)

Answer (score -2):

I like the intent of your variables, but try condensing them. For example, a Luxury Index variable (new car models can be fully loaded with all the possible amenities (2) or missing some (1) or base (0)). A Power variable (horsepower, size of engine,...). Also, an Efficiency variable (miles per gallon highway and for city).

An important missing variable(s), I suspect, that impacts price is the popularity/associated awards and the car's model year. Relatedly, the car's safety rating and also negatively, does the car have any reported accidents.

You may get better results (your adjusted R-square is not impressive) by attempting the regression modeling within classification categories (luxury cars, economy, midsize, sport utility, electric cars, ....). This assumes people are shopping for the best price within a category and may reduce the number of explanatory variables and an overfitting problem.

[EDIT] Per provided comments, it is time to present the wisdom [cited here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Under_what_circumstances_could_we_use_stepwise_linear_hierarchical_and_Multilevel_regressions), to quote:

> - Regression analysis is the art and science of fitting straight lines to patterns of data.
> - Stepwise regression is a semi-automated process of building a model by successively adding or removing variables based solely on the t-statistics of their estimated coefficients.

The word 'art' and references to the perceived value of inferential R-square are not compatible in the context of stepwise regression. It is hard enough to have the right variables enter the stepwise regression with the correct sign and an adequate significance level.

Comment: Particularly for inferential modeling, the $R^2$ is quite strong.

Comment: Dave: Having performed many stepwise regressions, adding a variable like # of doors, likely a poor proxy for a car's class, is not a path to a good model even if it  does seemingly improves R-square. This knowledge is gained from experience.

Comment: [Stepwise regression has been debunked. The first criticism is particularly pertinent here.](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/)